Warden Docker installation for Magento 2
I am trying to setup Warden (https://github.com/wardenenv/) installation for Magento 2 development. I am using MAMP on Mac OS Ventura, in location /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/m2. I do these commands first:
mkdir m2
cd m2
warden env-init magento245 magento2

Then I write the file using instructions from https://magetu.com/how-to-install-magento-2-4-5-with-warden/?i=1
After that:
warden sign-certificate magento245.test
warden env up

On this step I am getting a problem with php fm like so:
⠋ Container magento245-php-fpm-1           Starting                                                                                                        0.0s 
Error response from daemon: Mounts denied: 
The path /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento245/pub/media is not shared from the host and is not known to Docker.
You can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> Resources -> File Sharing.

How can I solve this problem and continue installing Magento 2? Is there a more straightforward way to install Magento 2 on Mac Air M1 running Ventura?
